# Iterate Array and add each consecutive array value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an amount.  I want to iterate the array starting from the first value and if I add the next value and it equals amount then those two values in the array should be returned.  If it doesn't equal the value, try to add the next one after that one and check if it equals the amount.

And then return the array of values that when added up equals the amount

example

Lets say I have an array of `[1,2,3,4,7]`
and an amount `6`

I know that I can make 6 by adding 1+2+3 so I want to return `[1,2,3]` back.

it's the iterating through the start of the array and then checking whether I add the next if it equals 6 and if not, try to add the next one also and see it equals 6...and so on till I get the values that when added together do equal 6.

On other words find the values in this array that when added together make up 6.

Comment: I don't know what to try I'm new to ruby and I don't have a real good idea.  This is literally the first day looking up the language

Comment: Take a look at the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) for the algorithm. There is a quite short recursive solution.

Comment: ok thx, I'll check that out now

Comment: With the array `[1,2,3,4,7]` and the value `6`, how do you decide to return `[1,2,3]` instead of `[1,1,1,3]` or `[1,1,1,1,1,1]`?

Comment: @Jordan no idea, very good question :)  one I'm trying to figure out too

Comment: @Jordan well I have tests that are looking for a certain outcome..so that's how.  But yea if I didn't have tests, it could be anything.  So I at least know what my output should be, I just gotta implement it.  So for this lets focus on consecutive additions, not doubling stuff, I'll take that out for now.

Comment: I took out the second example, I'll concentrate on the first scenario, adding consecutive numbers (after sorting the array asc first of course)

Comment: Code is worth 10,000 words. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: ...@Jordan, I don't see the connection with the coin problem, as the OP has made no mention of using elements of the array multiple times to obtain the desired sum.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The OP has updated the question and removed the example.

Comment: @sschmeck, thanks. I looked at the edits and see what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,7]
tot = 6
```

**Case 1: The elements to be summed are the first `n` elements of the array**

*Not very efficient, but reads well:*

```
idx = arr.size.times.find { |i| arr[0..i].reduce(:+) == tot }
idx ? arr[0..idx] : nil
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

*More efficient:*

```
t = 0
idx = arr.size.times.find { |i| t += arr[i]; t == tot }
idx ? arr[0..idx] : nil
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

*Use recursion*

```
def partial_sum(arr, remaining)
  return nil if arr.empty?
  first, *rest = arr
  if remaining == first
    [first]
  else
    ret = partial_sum(rest, remaining-first)
    ret ? [first, *ret] : nil
  end
end

partial_sum(arr, 6)
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
partial_sum(arr, 7)
  #=> nil
```

**Case 2: the elements to be summed can be any elements of the array**

```
def sum_subarrays(arr, tot)
  (0...arr.size).each do |n| 
    b = arr.combination(n).find { |a| a.reduce(:+) == tot }
    b ? (return b) : nil
  end
  nil
end

(1..17).each do |tot|
  v = sum_subarrays(arr, tot)
  puts "sum_subarrays(arr, #{tot}) = #{v ? v : 'nil'}"
end
sum_subarrays(arr, 1)  = [1]
sum_subarrays(arr, 2)  = [2]
sum_subarrays(arr, 3)  = [3]
sum_subarrays(arr, 4)  = [4]
sum_subarrays(arr, 5)  = [1, 4]
sum_subarrays(arr, 6)  = [2, 4]
sum_subarrays(arr, 7)  = [7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 8)  = [1, 7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 9)  = [2, 7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 10) = [3, 7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 11) = [4, 7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 12) = [1, 4, 7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 13) = [2, 4, 7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 14) = [3, 4, 7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 15) = [1, 3, 4, 7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 16) = [2, 3, 4, 7]
sum_subarrays(arr, 17) = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,7]
amount = 17

master_array = (1..array.size).map { |i| array.each_slice(i).to_a }

master_array.each.with_index do |e,i| 
  p e[0] if master_array[i][0].inject(:+) == amount
end
```

Comment: what is p e[0]?  I'm not that familiar with ruby syntax

Comment: @WTF `p` is a shortcut for the `inspect` method. When used with an array, it returns the array. Compare with `puts`, which would print each element of the array and return `nil`. In this case `e` represents the current element in the iteration, which is also an array. The e[0] notation prints the element of the array at index 0. Consider the array `e = [1, 2, 3]`, then `e[0] = 1`, `e[1]=2` and `e[2] = 3`.

Comment: To be honest my solution to Case 1 is a bit overcomplicated. @CarySwoveland has a much cleaner and easer to read solution for Case 1. And obviously he's considered the more complex Case 2.